# how to receive data from telnet connection in python

Tags: python, linux, sockets

I want to create program that if some one connects to my pc at port 43 and sends some data for example website name
then I perform some function on that website name and return final value
but this program is not function

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import socket
import urllib2
s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = '192.168.0.140' # Get local machine name
BUFFER_SIZE = 1000000000
port = 43        # Reserve a port for your service.
s.bind((host, port))        # Bind to the port

s.listen(5)                 # Now wait for client connection.
while True:
   c, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
   print 'Got connection from', addr
   data = c.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
   print data
   x = urllib2.urlopen('http://192.168.0.65:2020/?websitename='+data ).read()
   print x
   c.send(x)
   c.close()                # Close the connection
```

Also other problem is while testing if I close this script by hitting ctrl + c then it exits with traceback, but main problem is if next time I run this script then it shows following error

```
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

so I have to change port everytime I start script which is really painful

Any suggestions will be helpful, thank you

Comment: I think you should be using a higher port number. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers). Ports <1024 are generally reserved for better known purposes, may already be in use for some standard thing, and may require root privileges to bind to.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use ports below 1000, if you are not sure that you need them. Why, you can read here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Speaking about telnet what you mean? Network protocol http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet ? Or something else?

Comment: When some one connects to my pc using telnet and types some data
and I want to do processing on that data

Comment: You just need your client to agree to connect to a higher port number. For instance, according to the Wikipedia article we both linked, 43 is used for `whois`, so you should not be using it. Also +1 to the new user to help get enough rep to comment. ;)

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist What I am making is whois response server only, where clients send me request of domain name, and I pass that req to other app  x = urllib2.urlopen('http://192.168.0.65:2020/?websitename='+data ).read() and then print its response back to user